# Merge two data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I created two data frames:

```
tab1 <- medivmind %>% select(medi_total_factor, participant_id)  %>% 
  filter(!is.na(medi_total_factor)) %>%
  count(medi_total_factor, .drop = FALSE) %>% add_column(diet = "medi") %>%
  rename(n_medi = n, score = medi_total_factor)
DF1  
   score n_medi diet  
1      0      0 medi  
2    0.5      0 medi  
3      1      7 medi  
4    1.5      0 medi  
5      2     12 medi  
6    2.5      0 medi  
...  

tab2 <- medivmind %>% select(mind_total_factor, participant_id) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(mind_total_factor)) %>%
  count(mind_total_factor, .drop = FALSE) %>% add_column(diet = "mind") %>%
  rename(n_mind = n, score = mind_total_factor)
DF2  
   score n_mind diet  
1      0      0 mind  
2    0.5      0 mind  
3      1      0 mind  
4    1.5      0 mind  
5      2      0 mind  
6    2.5      0 mind  
...
```

I want to merge them to look like:

```
   score n_mind diet  
1      0      0 mind  
2      0      0 medi  
3    0.5      0 mind  
4    0.5      0 medi  
5      1      0 mind  
6      1      0 medi  
7    1.5      0 mind  
8    1.5      0 medi  
...
```

I've tried rbind, cbind, left_join but I keep getting the following (or variation of):

```
   score n_medi diet score n_mind diet  
1      0      0 medi     0      0 mind  
2    0.5      0 medi   0.5      0 mind  
3      1      7 medi     1      0 mind  
4    1.5      0 medi   1.5      0 mind  
5      2     12 medi     2      0 mind
```

Comment: Please run `dput(DF1)` and `dput(DF2)`, then copy and paste the output of it

Answer (score 0):

**Update II:**
If you want `NA` in both columns we could use `across`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tab3 <- left_join(tab1, tab2, by="score") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("diet")) %>% 
  select(score, n_medi, n_mind, diet=value) %>% 
  group_by(score) %>% 
  arrange(desc(diet), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(n_medi, n_mind), ~ifelse(lead(.)==., ., NA)))
```

```
   score n_medi n_mind diet 
   <dbl>  <int>  <int> <chr>
 1   0        0      0 mind 
 2   0       NA     NA medi 
 3   0.5      0      0 mind 
 4   0.5     NA     NA medi 
 5   1        7      0 mind 
 6   1       NA     NA medi 
 7   1.5      0      0 mind 
 8   1.5     NA     NA medi 
 9   2       12      0 mind 
10   2       NA     NA medi 
11   2.5      0      0 mind 
12   2.5     NA     NA medi
```

**Update:**
Do you want this:

```
tab3 <- left_join(tab1, tab2, by="score") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("diet")) %>% 
  select(score, n_medi, n_mind, diet=value) %>% 
  group_by(score) %>% 
  arrange(desc(diet), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(n_medi = ifelse(lead(n_medi==n_medi), n_medi, NA))
```

```
   score n_medi n_mind diet 
   <dbl>  <int>  <int> <chr>
 1   0        0      0 mind 
 2   0       NA      0 medi 
 3   0.5      0      0 mind 
 4   0.5     NA      0 medi 
 5   1        7      0 mind 
 6   1       NA      0 medi 
 7   1.5      0      0 mind 
 8   1.5     NA      0 medi 
 9   2       12      0 mind 
10   2       NA      0 medi 
11   2.5      0      0 mind 
12   2.5     NA      0 medi
```

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(DF1, DF2, by="score") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("diet")) %>% 
  select(score, n_medi, diet=value) %>% 
  group_by(score) %>% 
  arrange(desc(diet), .by_group = TRUE)
```

```
  score n_medi diet 
   <dbl>  <int> <chr>
 1   0        0 mind 
 2   0        0 medi 
 3   0.5      0 mind 
 4   0.5      0 medi 
 5   1        7 mind 
 6   1        7 medi 
 7   1.5      0 mind 
 8   1.5      0 medi 
 9   2       12 mind 
10   2       12 medi 
11   2.5      0 mind 
12   2.5      0 medi
```

data:

```
> dput(DF1)
structure(list(score = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5), n_medi = c(0L, 
0L, 7L, 0L, 12L, 0L), diet = c("medi", "medi", "medi", "medi", 
"medi", "medi")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
> dput(DF2)
structure(list(score = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5), n_mind = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), diet = c("mind", "mind", "mind", "mind", 
"mind", "mind")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: tab3 <- left_join(tab1, tab2, by="score") %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("diet")) %>% 
  select(score, n_medi, n_mind, diet=value) %>% 
  group_by(score) %>% 
  arrange(desc(diet), .by_group = TRUE)      can I add NA to the repeated values in the n_medi and n_mind?

Comment: please see my update.